# If $X_i$ are iid Bernoulli, and $N$ is a r.v., does $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i, N=n\right) = P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_i$ are iid $Bern(p)$ random variable, and $N$ is a random variable as well, does:

$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i, N=n\right) = P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)
$$?

In other words, if the sum require $N$, does the $N=n$ fall off?

Comment: what does your notation even mean?

Comment: You haven't written a conditional r.v.  To write $X$ is conditional on $Y$, we write $X\mid Y$.  So, if you want that sum conditional on $N = n$, you write:
$$P(\sum_{i = 1}^N X_i\mid N = n)$$
This is in general very different from your notation, as your notation with the comma implies that you're working with a joint probability, instead of a conditional one.

Comment: @Mark Sorry for the confusion, I am intending to work with the joint probability and NOT the conditional. I just mentioned the conditional to describe how the summation depends on $N$ as a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

If the $X_i$'s are independent of $N$, then

$$ \Pr \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i = x \left| N=n \right. \right) = \Pr \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =x\right) $$

The left side of the equation above is the probability that the $X_i$'s sum up to $x$ conditional on $N=n$.

However, if we maintain the assumption that the $X_i$'s are independent of $N$, taking what you've written in your question,

$$ \Pr \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i = x , N=n \right) = \Pr \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =x\right) \Pr(N=n) $$

Comment: Your notation is not the notation in the question. The latter is meaningless. I am not sure how one can answer the question under the circumstances.

Comment: @wolfies There are problems with the notation in the question, but I think given what's written there, one can reasonably infer that this is, with very high probability, the answer to the question they meant to ask. I'll be happy to delete this answer if it turns out that the original intended question was something else entirely.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Thanks, so that is to say I cannot just combine and drop off the $N$ term if its NOT independent?

Comment: @user321627 Yes, exactly.